# what is the order of the logic and the multi-sortedness of the structures required for rigorous math in ...

Tags: logic, foundations, higher-order-logic

Might be a not well-posed question but I hope it makes sense and can be clearly answered.
Iwant to know what is the order of the logic required to work with the following areas of mathematics, to write their theorems , proving them, and how do their structures (as a base set(s), functions, realtions) look like.

- Linear algebra
- mathematical analysis (real analysis)

and most important

- differential geometry
- functional analysis

Comment: I don't think you need any formal logic to prove theorems in any of those fields. I bet there are mathematicians who have published papers in at least on of the mentioned areas but would have to look up the definitions of higher-order or multi-sorted logic.

Comment: I suppose Jouko Väänänen's papers "Second-Order Logic and Foundations of Mathematics" (https://philpapers.org/rec/VAASLA) and "Second Order Logic or Set Theory?" (https://philpapers.org/rec/VNNSOL) could give good insights relevant to your question.